# Unable to print node properties in DSE graph

Tags: graph, datastax, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

Apologies as this might be very basic question on the topic but I am new to Gremlin/DSE Graph and i tried many ways to extract data i am inserting to my graph but somehow i am unable to make it work.

Here is what i have:
1. Graph with allow_scans set to true 
2. Schema with propertyKey and vertexes defined and materialized index on NodeID of all Vertexes.

There are no relationships right now, just vertexes with data points.

I wrote a program to insert all my nodes to DSE Graph which is working successfully as i get response like below after program created every Vertex:

```
Result({u'id': {u'out_vertex': {u'community_id': 853347840, u'~label': u'vertex', u'member_id': 14}, u'~type': u'Name', u'local_id': u'00000000-0000-8012-0000-000000000000'}, u'value': u'amount', u'label': u'Name'})]
```

Ok So now the nodes are inserted, i want to extract them and print their names:
So i did:

```
g.V().hasLabel('FIELD').has('NodeID','2559b635f077e86c7370ab1c4c798a06').values('Name');
```

Above failed successfully with blank result. I mean it runs successfully with null output like there is no error but then there is no output. (null in gremlin-console and 'Success - No Results' in DataStax Studio)

Then i came across documentation that graph will not know if the 'has' will only return one node or more, so i used next for iterating as per documentation and tutorials:

```
g.V().hasLabel('FIELD').has('NodeID','2559b635f077e86c7370ab1c4c798a06').next().values('Name');
```

Even this failed with

> org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException

(Datastax studio doesnt show more information) - How can i debug this further?

I even came across lambda approach in which i use map :

```
g.V().hasLabel('FIELD').has('NodeID','2559b635f077e86c7370ab1c4c798a06').map{it.get().value('Name')};
```

which responded with 'it' not being defined.

(i even tried valueMap - not sure if it was even required)

What am i doing wrong to find and print properties values of a node?

Any directions or query which can help me extract the names and other properties? Even a multi-step query? however i don't think this should be that complicated.

**UPDATE**:

As per answer i get the following traceback:

```
gremlin> :> g.V().hasLabel('FIELD').has('NodeID','2559b635f077e86c7370ab1c4c798a06').valueMap(true).next();
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:170)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.commands.SubmitCommand.execute(SubmitCommand.groovy:41)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:104)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.executeCommand(Groovysh.groovy:259)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:84)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:124)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1215)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:152)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:401)
```

I am able to do some similar operations in another graph. Is something wrong with the graph?

**UPDATE 2**

My Graph vertices were wrongly defined.

The key to drill down to this solution is in the `~label` in the result. It points to `vertex` instead it should be `Field`

While defining the data insert team had put label in quotes when they had to put mention label without quotes. Hence i was not able to traverse the nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure to iterate the traversal. Most commonly you would use either:

- `iterate()` get zero result
- `next()` get one result
- `toList()` get many results

I'd guess that `NodeID` is unique, so try something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('FIELD').has('NodeID','2559b635f077e86c7370ab1c4c798a06').
values('Name').next();
```

If you're interested in all of the properties on that vertex, try:

```
g.V().hasLabel('FIELD').has('NodeID','2559b635f077e86c7370ab1c4c798a06').
valueMap(true).next();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have updated with the trace which i am getting. Looks like something is wrong with the graph. please can you help me find out what could be the problem here. 
g.V().hasLabel('FIELD').has('NodeID','2559b635f077e86c7370ab1c4c798a06').
values('Name') works in another graph with similar nodes. Not sure what went wrong with this one.

Comment: My Vertices were defined in a wrong fashion. Your answer is correct though. Thanks