# Titan gremlin console and java returns different result for group().by() query

Tags: java, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am using Titan [1.0.0](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/) supported by cassandra 2.1.7 as backend storage. While trying to execute the same query on gremlin console and java program, I am getting 2 the output in two different formats. I am using the gremlin console provided by titan-1.0.0-hadoop1 and for java I am using TinkerPop Gremlin [3.0.1-incubating](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/).

**Gremlin Console:**

```
gremlin> g.V().has('msid',within(-2128958273, 2147477890)).as('in').local(outE('hie_child').has('hostid_e',within(153,83)).order().by('hrank',incr).limit(5)).group().by(outV().id()).by(inV().id().fold())
```

> ==>[77467688:[1531850904, 4742561976, 1009049792, 1010020408, 1053356264], 73363640:[2060075072, 3698942184, 6776295608, 7030726848,
>   35401920]]

I am getting the expected type of output i.e. `Map<VertexId, List<VertexId>>`

But while executing the same query in java program, I am getting `Map<VertexId, BulkSet>`. The `BulkSet` includes a counter indicating the number of times a particular entry is added in the result set. Can someone please tell me if there is a way to get the similar result in java as gremlin console.

**Java:**

```
List<Map<Object, Object>> list = g.V().has("msid", P.within(-2128958273,2147477890)).as("in").local(__.outE("hie_child").has("hostid_e", P.within(153,83)).order().by("hrank", Order.incr).limit(5)).group().by(__.outV().id()).by(__.inV().id().fold()).fold().next();

System.out.println(list);
```

> [{77467688={1531850904=1, 4742561976=1, 1009049792=1, 1010020408=1,
>   1053356264=1}, 73363640={2060075072=1, 3698942184=1, 6776295608=1,
>   7030726848=1, 35401920=1}}]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See answer given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43284707/5025129

- `iterate()` get zero result
- `next()` get one result
- `toList()` get many results

You should call on `toList()` rather than `next()`.

This is also a good read on result iteration http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration

EDIT: There appears to be a bug in TinkerPop 3.0.x related to this, and it is reproducible in the Gremlin Console, but it is fixed in TinkerPop 3.1.x. Actually, you should be able to use the `BulkSet` just fine as it only contains values. What you're seeing is the difference in the `BulkSet.toString()` vs `ArrayList.toString()`.

TinkerPop 3.0.x

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin>  l = g.V(1).local( outE('knows') ).group().by( __.outV().id() ).by( __.inV().id().fold() ).fold().next()
==>[1:[2, 4]]
gremlin> l[0].getClass()
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.GroupStep$GroupMap
gremlin> l[0].values().iterator().next().getClass()
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.util.BulkSet
gremlin> bs = l[0].values().iterator().next()
==>2
==>4
gremlin> bs[0].getClass()
==>class java.lang.Integer
gremlin> bs[1].getClass()
==>class java.lang.Integer
gremlin> bs.toString()
==>{2=1, 4=1}
```

TinkerPop 3.1.x

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin>  l = g.V(1).local( outE('knows') ).group().by( __.outV().id() ).by( __.inV().id().fold() ).fold().next()
==>[1:[2, 4]]
gremlin> l[0].getClass()
==>class java.util.HashMap
gremlin>  l[0].values().iterator().next().getClass()
==>class java.util.ArrayList
gremlin> bs = l[0].values().iterator().next()
==>2
==>4
gremlin> bs[0].getClass()
==>class java.lang.Integer
gremlin> bs[1].getClass()
==>class java.lang.Integer
gremlin> bs.toString()
==>[2, 4]
```

You could [build the `titan11` branch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/S9j5Zclumd8/mZp-6OmoFwAJ) which uses TinkerPop 3.1.1 or you could try [JanusGraph](http://janusgraph.org).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't help me. The problem I am facing is that the values of the Map returned in java contains a count against each value i.e. `{77467688={1531850904=1, 4742561976=1, 1009049792=1, 1010020408=1, 1053356264=1}`, whereas I am only interested in the values as returned by the gremlin console  `[77467688:[1531850904, 4742561976, 1009049792, 1010020408, 1053356264]`.

Comment: This appears to be a bug, so I've made an edit to my answer.