# Remote Gremlin Server graph mutation with Java / Scala

Tags: java, server, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to get modify vertices on a remote Gremlin Server using a traversal but it seems that only in the traversal in which a vertex is created I can also add properties, when starting a new traversal I properties are not added.

Scala/Java cluster connection setup code:

```
val mapper = GryoMapper.build()
val cluster = Cluster.build().serializer(new GryoMessageSerializerV1d0(mapper)).create
val client = cluster.connect[org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client.ClusteredClient]()
val graph = EmptyGraph.instance()
val g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "g"))
```

this works:

```
val v1 = g.addV("person").property("name","stephen").next()
```

this does not:

```
g.V(v1.id()).property("age","27")
```

this does not either and even throws a java.lang.IllegalStateException (propertyAdditionNotSupported) because the vertex is a org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferenceVertex:

```
v1.property("age","27")
```

If I use a Gremlin Console and remote connect to the Gremlin Server I do both without any issues.

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
gremlin> :> g.addV('person').property('name','stephen')
==>v[82128]
gremlin> :> g.V(82128).property('age','27')
==>v[82128]
gremlin> :> g.V(82128).valueMap()
==>[name:[stephen],age:[27]]
```

Is the Java remote implementation bugged or am I missing something?

Comment: found the solution, had to add .iterate() behind the traversal, still trying to understand why...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what Graph implementation you are using but this works for me with TinkerGraph:

```
gremlin> graph = EmptyGraph.instance()
==>emptygraph[empty]
gremlin> cluster = Cluster.open()
==>localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin>  g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "g"))
==>graphtraversalsource[emptygraph[empty], standard]
gremlin> v = g.addV().property('name','stephen').next()
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V(v.id()).property('favorite','red')
==>v[0]
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[name:[stephen],favorite:[red]]
```

I will note than in your case you don't `next()` out the vertex from:

```
val v1 = g.addV("person").property("name","stephen")
```

I assume that even in Gremlin Scala syntax you should have to do:

```
val v1 = g.addV("person").property("name","stephen").next()
```

otherwise `v1` will just be a `Traversal` instance and you get the `id()` of the `Traversal` and not the `Vertex`. So I think that should fix your problem.

Note that `v1.property("age","27")` will not work for the reason you explained - that vertex is "detached" and you can't work with it directly except by passing it back into another traversal. You should also be able to do this on most graphs:

```
gremlin> g.V(v).property('favorite','red')
==>v[0]
```

without referencing the `id()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the correct vertex-id but stripped some alternative Scala code (I edited my original question and added .next()). Your example is from within Gremlin Console I assume and that works, I can also do this in the Gremlin Console. But a remote connection from within a Scala/Java program does not allow me to modify existing vertices. 
I tried both TinkerGraph and JanusGraph, both are not working so I assume it is in the Java implementation..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to [iterate the traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43824632/5025129). Stephen's answer makes some mention of this. The Gremlin Console automatically iterates the traversal, while you must explicitly do this yourself otherwise.

- `iterate()` get zero result
- `next()` get one result
- `toList()` get many results

This tutorial is also a good read on result iteration http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/#result-iteration